# Create a new firebase app from API

Tags: firebase

My question is simple, is there any way to create a new Firebase app (app app name + url) using javascript API?

Comment: Not that I know off. But you can manually create a container for all your apps and then put each 'app' in a child under the root. That's how I deal with it at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. Firebase rarely (if ever) recommends someone create multiple Firebases for their application. It's much easier to use a child location (like `<Your Firebase>.firebaseio.com/Client1`) to segregate data.

Comment: how about if one wants userA@client1.com and userB@client1.com to be able to access /Client1 but not /Client3? Would that be possible with rules? Thanks.