# Firebase Drawing Demo and Sessions

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm interested in using Firebase, but have some questions.

One demo I'm really interested in is the drawing demo: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/lijxbwexqv1

The key thing I'm curious about is how sessions in Firebase are handled and established. How is a random session key being created, and also how is it being put in the URL to establish where the data is coming from (see code below).

```
//Create a reference to the pixel data for our drawing.
var pixelDataRef = new Firebase('https://lijxbwexqv1.firebaseio-demo.com/');
```

I'd like to create an educational app. Where the user is shown a picture of something, and then on their phone are seeing corresponding information to the picture they're being shown. I know this is different from the drawing demo, but the concepts of sessions is similar. Basically each user would have a "session" or a firebase data set--that they could access using a custom URL.

Any help or pointers (docs even) regarding the establishment and storage sessions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: There is no Firebase API to create firebases. But you can easily host each session in a <sessionid> child under your single Firebase. Also see this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763839/create-a-new-firebase-app-from-api

Comment: Ok that seems to do exactly what I need. How scalable is something like that (creating a child for each session)? How many children would it take before Firebase got really bogged down for example?

Comment: One more question, in this screenshot: http://imgur.com/srDhkRF ...the highlighted red portion, is created every time i send data to the firebase. What would you call that unique key that's generated? And is there anyway to retrieve that via the API. essentially I could use those as a "sessionId" potentially if that's possible.

Comment: The question how many children it takes to bog down Firebase is way too broad. I doubt there is a known limit and recommend the approach that "if you get the number of users that takes down Firebase, that is a good problem to have".

Comment: Please open a separate question for that last bit. But search/read before you do, as it might already have been asked/answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "session" keys are random strings. They are generated [in the source](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/js/main.js) as follows:

```
UserSession.prototype.generateSessionID_ = function () {
  if (window.isDebugMode) {
    return "chat";
  } else {
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var retVal = chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26, 1));
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      retVal = retVal + chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length, 1));
    }
    return retVal;
  }
}
```

You could also simply use [Firebase.push()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/push.html), which generates random ids that also serve as sequential, chronological record ids:

```
function generateSessionId(ref) {
   return ref.push().name();
}

var fb = new Firebase(URL);
console.log( generateSessionId(fb) );
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for this. I'm currently using .push() on my data, so I'm seeing those random sequential Id's. I'm curious, how unique are those? Are they similar to UUIDs in that collision / repetition is nearly impossible?

Comment: They are time based UUIDs, so very similar indeed, except that they sort lexicographically, which means they always appear in order when sorted by ID :)

Comment: Nice thanks again for the help, doing some really cool stuff with a "synced" mobile and desktop session!