# Create firebase instance programmatically

Tags: android, firebase

i am very new to firebase but excited about learning more, i have tried the simple chat and it works great. I am building a simple product review mobile app on android, i want to find out is it possible to create a firebase automatically from code in my java?  I want to create different group chats but give the user the ability to create a group chat from their mobile phone.

Comment: Why not just create each group chat as a child of one Firebase? This is a good idea for many reasons: all your data is under one firebase, you don't have to worry about multiple sets of security rules, you don't bill different chats separately, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was of great help and i have implemented it well. Now is it possible to delete one message from a chat, just a single message under a child? For example                                                              Ali: hi                                                                   Alex: hey                                                                  Ali: am good                                                                  So is it possible to delete only one of these messages from firbase without deleting all of them under that particular child?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a new firebase app from API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763839/create-a-new-firebase-app-from-api)

Comment: @Aly check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html, the last section is on removing data from a list. Basically you would need to keep a reference to each message, then just call `ref.remove()` on the appropriate reference to delete that message from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a single Firebase, with each group chat as a child of it. Using Firebase's [lists](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html) functionality, Firebase can automatically generate an ID for each group chat. Then, in each chat, you can have a list of messages which corresponds to the contents of the chat.