# Using Firebase for generic app distribution

Tags: firebase

I'm developing a mobile application which I would like to distribute globally. The app is targeted for managers who want their employees to update data as they are on-the-go, while the manager has a web dashboard that collects and dices the data.
The architecture I would like to implement, is that the manager logs in to the product's website, creates an account, and gets a code. Employees are then asked to download the app, and enter that code upon initial setup.

My question is about the back-end implementation of the setup - I would like for each new customer to have their own firebase instance, which is automatically set up and registered when the account is created.
It seems like the API does not support creating new accounts or new repositories/instances. 
Is there a way to create an account/instance using a script? If not, would one instance be able to hold potentially a very large number of tables, each table being a root for a specific customer and their data?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763839/create-a-new-firebase-app-from-api

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll follow advice given there, and will create new branch per customer.

However, I did manage to hack a way into creating new account. Posting it here in order for the FireBase team to decide whether this is a feature or a bug: 
curl -X POST https://admin.firebase.com/firebase/name_of_new_instance -d "token=can_be_found_in_previous_calls" -d "appName=name_of_new_instance"

Comment: Feel free to reach out to support@firebase.com with that last question. I'll mark your original question as a duplicate.